# How do I make a submission of a CNN?

Tags: machine-learning, neural-network, deep-learning, cnn, image-classification

I have built a CNN to do image classification for images representing different weather conditions. I have 4 classes of images : Haze, Rainy, Snowy, Sunny.

I have built my CNN and evaluated the performances. N ow I have been given a blind test set, so images without a label, and I have to make a submission. So I have to buld a .csv file which contains should contain one line for each predicted class of images, so it should have the structure ,. Thus each line should be a string which identifies the image and its prediction.

Now the problem is that I don't understand how to do this. I am really confused because I have never done something similar.

My code is the following:

```
trainingset = '/content/drive/My Drive/Colab Notebooks/Train'
testset = '/content/drive/My Drive/Colab Notebooks/Test_HWI'


batch_size = 31
train_datagen = ImageDataGenerator(
    featurewise_center=True,
    featurewise_std_normalization=True,
    rescale = 1. / 255,\
    zoom_range=0.1,\
    rotation_range=10,\
    width_shift_range=0.1,\
    height_shift_range=0.1,\
    horizontal_flip=True,\
    vertical_flip=False)


train_generator = train_datagen.flow_from_directory(
    directory=trainingset,
    target_size=(256, 256),
    color_mode="rgb",
    batch_size=batch_size,
    class_mode="categorical",
    shuffle=True
)


test_datagen = ImageDataGenerator(
    featurewise_center=True,
    featurewise_std_normalization=True,
    rescale = 1. / 255
   )



test_generator = test_datagen.flow_from_directory(
    directory=testset,
    target_size=(256, 256),
    color_mode="rgb",
    batch_size=batch_size,
    class_mode="categorical",
    shuffle=False
)

num_samples = train_generator.n
num_classes = train_generator.num_classes
input_shape = train_generator.image_shape

classnames = [k for k,v in train_generator.class_indices.items()]
```

then I build the network:

```
def Network(input_shape, num_classes, regl2 = 0.0001, lr=0.0001):

model = Sequential()

# C1 Convolutional Layer 
model.add(Conv2D(filters=32, input_shape=input_shape, kernel_size=(3,3),\
                 strides=(1,1), padding='valid'))
model.add(Activation('relu'))
# Pooling
model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2,2), strides=(2,2), padding='valid'))
# Batch Normalisation before passing it to the next layer
model.add(BatchNormalization())

# C2 Convolutional Layer
model.add(Conv2D(filters=64, kernel_size=(3,3), strides=(1,1), padding='valid'))
model.add(Activation('relu'))
# Batch Normalisation
model.add(BatchNormalization())

# C3 Convolutional Layer
model.add(Conv2D(filters=128, kernel_size=(3,3), strides=(1,1), padding='valid'))
model.add(Activation('relu'))
# Batch Normalisation
model.add(BatchNormalization())

# C4 Convolutional Layer
model.add(Conv2D(filters=256, kernel_size=(3,3), strides=(1,1), padding='valid'))
model.add(Activation('relu'))
#Pooling
model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2,2), strides=(2,2), padding='valid'))
# Batch Normalisation
model.add(BatchNormalization())

# C5 Convolutional Layer
model.add(Conv2D(filters=400, kernel_size=(3,3), strides=(1,1), padding='valid'))
model.add(Activation('relu'))
# Pooling
model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2,2), strides=(2,2), padding='valid'))
# Batch Normalisation
model.add(BatchNormalization())

 # C6 Convolutional Layer
model.add(Conv2D(filters=512, kernel_size=(3,3), strides=(1,1), padding='valid'))
model.add(Conv2D(filters=512, kernel_size=(3,3), strides=(1,1), padding='valid'))
model.add(Activation('relu'))
# Pooling
model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2,2), strides=(2,2), padding='valid'))
# Batch Normalisation
model.add(BatchNormalization())

 # C7 Convolutional Layer
model.add(Conv2D(filters=800, kernel_size=(3,3), strides=(1,1), padding='valid'))
model.add(Conv2D(filters=800, kernel_size=(3,3), strides=(1,1), padding='valid'))
model.add(Activation('relu'))
# Pooling
model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2,2), strides=(2,2), padding='valid'))
# Batch Normalisation
model.add(BatchNormalization())

# C8 Convolutional Layer
model.add(Conv2D(filters=1000, kernel_size=(3,3), strides=(1,1), padding='valid'))
model.add(Activation('relu'))
# Pooling
model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2,2), strides=(2,2), padding='valid'))
# Batch Normalisation
model.add(BatchNormalization())

# Flatten
model.add(Flatten())

flatten_shape = (input_shape[0]*input_shape[1]*input_shape[2],)

# D1 Dense Layer
model.add(Dense(4096, input_shape=flatten_shape, kernel_regularizer=regularizers.l2(regl2)))
model.add(Activation('relu'))
# Dropout
model.add(Dropout(0.4))
# Batch Normalisation
model.add(BatchNormalization())

# D2 Dense Layer
model.add(Dense(4096, kernel_regularizer=regularizers.l2(regl2)))
model.add(Activation('relu'))
# Dropout
model.add(Dropout(0.4))
# Batch Normalisation
model.add(BatchNormalization())

# D3 Dense Layer
model.add(Dense(1000,kernel_regularizer=regularizers.l2(regl2)))
model.add(Activation('relu'))
# Dropout
model.add(Dropout(0.4))
# Batch Normalisation
model.add(BatchNormalization())

# Output Layer
model.add(Dense(num_classes))
model.add(Activation('softmax'))

# Compile

adam = optimizers.Adam(lr=lr)
model.compile(loss='categorical_crossentropy', optimizer=adam, metrics=['accuracy'])

return model

#create the model
model = Network(input_shape,num_classes)
model.summary()
```

I train the network:

```
steps_per_epoch=train_generator.n//train_generator.batch_size
val_steps=test_generator.n//test_generator.batch_size+1

try:
    history = model.fit_generator(train_generator, epochs=100, verbose=1,\
                    steps_per_epoch=steps_per_epoch,\
                    validation_data=test_generator,\
                    validation_steps=val_steps)
except KeyboardInterrupt:
    pass
```

now, I have the images without labels in the google drive, so I define the path to them:

```
blind_testSet = '/content/drive/My Drive/Colab Notebooks/blind_testset'
```

but now I don't know what shoul I do. I really don't know how to define the .csv file I mentioned above.

Can someone please help me? Thanks in advance.

[EDIT] Ok I am trying to make the predictions on the blind test set, but it is taking really a long time. What I have done is the following:

```
blind_testSet = '/content/drive/My Drive/Colab 
Notebooks/submission/blind_testset'

test_datagen_blind = ImageDataGenerator(
    featurewise_center=True,
    featurewise_std_normalization=True,
    rescale = 1. / 255
   )


test_generator_blind = test_datagen.flow_from_directory(
    directory=blind_testSet,
    target_size=(256, 256),
    color_mode="rgb",
    batch_size=batch_size,
    class_mode="categorical",
    shuffle=False
)

preds = model.predict_generator(test_generator_blind,verbose=1,steps=val_steps)
```

the images I have inside this blind test set are 1500, but is it normal that it takes so long? Thanks.

[EDIT 2] To try to make the submission I am trying to use a code similar to this:

```
def make_submission(model, filename="submission.csv"):
df = pd.read_csv("../input/test.csv")
X = df.values / 255
X = X.reshape(X.shape[0], 28, 28, 1)
preds = model.predict_classes(X)
subm = pd.DataFrame(data=list(zip(range(1, len(preds) + 1), preds)), columns=["ImageId", "Label"])
subm.to_csv(filename, index=False)
```

## return subm

but it seems to not work in my case. I have also tried to keep only the last 2 lines and use them, so :

```
 subm = pd.DataFrame(data=list(zip(range(1, len(preds) + 1), preds)), columns=["ImageId", "Label"])
subm.to_csv(filename, index=False)
```

can someone help me creating this csv file? Thanks.

Comment: The edit should probably be a new question instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to make predictions first. Than order these predictions to the ids in the blind_testSet. So something like this:

> `test_set=pd.read_csv(blind_testSet)
>   test_set["predicted_labels"]=model.predict(quntified pictures from test set)`

EDIT: on the question why is it taking so long to train:
you have **deep** convolutional layers. Backpropagating is very expensive process. A lot can be said on this topic how to speed up the computations, but lets say that you should be looking at utilizing [GPU power](https://www.tensorflow.org/guide/gpu)

Comment: sorry again, but I am not yet able to make a submission. I don't understand because I am using a generator to handle the images from a directory, and I can't find a way to build my desired .csv file. If you can, can you show me a way to do it? Thanks again.

Comment: Predicting doesn't use backpropagation, and should be much much faster than training. But that part should probably be a new question anyway...